# How to rewrite URL's in WooCommerce/WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, woocommerce

So I'm using WooCommerce for my webshop and I have the following question:

Right now my category link is `www.mywebsite.com/product-categorie/%category%/$sub_category%/ but my product link is www.mywebsite.com/product/%product%`

Is it possible to change the URL of my products to `www.mywebsite.com/product-categorie/%category%/$sub_category%/%product%`?

Comment: How are set your product permalinks?

Answer (score 0):

Products urls are not related to any WordPress theme and Product are part of WooCommerce plugin. The support forum for the WooCommerce plugin is located here for future reference.

https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce

You can set custom urls for WooCommerce from the WordPress > Permalinks section.